# Disconnect the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am assigning all the records from a model like this:

```
price_list = ClearinghousePrice.where(:c_or_t => 'C')
```

Then I want to delete some of the records from the pricelist before I use it for another operation. The trouble is when I delete records from the pricelist, they also get deleted from the model. Which I do not want. I want to keep the model in tact.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you need is NOT `delete` some records but `reject` some of your records. I will give you an example here.

Assuming you want to reject records with `id > 10` in `price_list`, you should use:

```
another_price_list = price_list.reject { |p| p.id > 10 }
```

Comment: Yang, seems like the right track. I entered this and I am getting empty brackets. 
another_price_list = price_list.reject { |p| p.clearinghouse_company_id = 1 }

Comment: It seems to have worked, I am trying to look through the records. It seems only company # 2 are remaining. However when I do another_price_list.count the count stays the same as the original file??

Comment: What do you mean by "original file"? The `another_price_list.count` equals to `price_list.count`?

Comment: Yes; another_price_list.count equals to price_list.count

Comment: This did it, and reduced the count. I eliminated the quote marks around the 1 another_price_list = price_list.reject { |p| p.clearinghouse_company_id == 1 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete_if` so you can put condition in your block code. Try to do this:

```
new_price_list = price_list.delete_if { |price| price.id > 10 }
```

I hope this help you.